# Path for assets for html

Tags: android, html, path

please help..
I have a HTML code to display a webview but the styles are found in the assets folder and need to put the path to these files in HTML and tried in various ways but /src/main/assets/web.css
file: ///android_asset/web.css does not work.   could say me how .

Comment: Are you asking how to reference an android asset from html?

Comment: I guess generally we are using this pattern  ~/assets/web.css.

Comment: Is your html file also in assets folder?

Comment: no, the html code, I have  wv_rae.loadData (htmls, "text / html", null);

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is one folder inside asset named: `home` and there is one file `index.html` inside `home` folder. So to load `index.html` i write code like this:

```
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home/index.html");
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I want to load the source but I not know  the path
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text / css" href = "fonts.css">

Comment: `font.css` is inside asset folder? and the file in which you are writing this code should be also inside asset folder. Then only it can find this css file.

Comment: yes,  file is in assets but does not load the fonts.

Comment: tell me one thing. `html` page is also inside `asset` folder right? @DiegoChiluisa

Comment: no, the html code, I have wv_rae.loadData (htmls, "text / html", null); because I generate code

Comment: wv rae.loadUrl loading the HTML file ("file: ///android_asset/webinfo.html");
works but I chiro generate the code and does not work well.cargando el archivo html  wv_rae.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webinfo.html");

Comment: @DiegoChiluisa `wv_rae.loadData(htmls, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);` Try this.